# Long tag names cause user card to wrap to the next line and become incorrectly aligned

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, design, user-card

I have just noticed a bug in the questions page while scrolling the list of questions in the [huawei-mobile-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huawei-mobile-services) tag: the user card is not correctly aligned to the right:

[image: screenshot showing user card all the way to the left, under the tags]

It is aligned to left, under the tags, when it should be aligned to the right. I believe this bug might be caused by tag names being too long, causing the user card to wrap to the next line.

To reproduce, click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huawei-mobile-services?tab=newest&page=3&pagesize=50), then scroll until you see the question with the same name as the photograph (some other questions exhibit this same bug, too).

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366329/profile-images-are-pushed-to-next-line-if-tags-extend-too-far-to-the-right

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Hmm, that seems to be the same bug, but that got marked [status-completed] 20 hours ago. The bug is still reproducible, at least on SO.

Comment: @cigien *"In any case, it looks like someone already pushed a fix for this before we'd even triaged it ;) It'll be live in the next build"*

Comment: @Nick Ah, I see. I should have read the full comment thread. Still, odd to mark it as [status-completed] before the fix is live. Technically correct I guess, but a bit confusing :/

Comment: @cigien Thank you. When will be next build?

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour I haven't the faintest idea, sorry. You might want to ask that in a comment on the linked MSE post.

Comment: @cigien I think it's not even "Technically correct". It's correct that's it's completed for the developer, but not for the deployment. And nothing is completed until it's verified, if you ask me.

Comment: @Scratte Yeah, that's possible. I'm not really sure what the [status-completed] tag means exactly. I suppose if the dev team is done with it, it's completed ;)

Comment: still there i just found another deleted my question as duplicate https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408355/question-formatting-issue-when-tags-to-long

Comment: Aaaand now they're left-aligned...

Comment: @TylerH And this is Stack Exchange; Where bugs produce another bugs. ;)

Comment: This appears to be have been fixed for a while and the [cross-dup Meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/366329) was just marked [status-completed].