# Updates/creation info of a post on the Home page seems to be broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, homepage, last-activity

The updates/creation info next to the tags on the [Home page](https://stackoverflow.com/) has a bug. The content's position seems to be dependent on the number/length of tags.

I feel like this bug was caused while trying to fix [this bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408352/11573842).

> [image]

Comment: Already reported on MSE: [Alignment issue in the “Top Questions” page](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/366481/289905).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

This has been fixed.  Here's a confirmation screenshot:

[image]

Comment: [status-completed] on [uber meta too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/366481/598066)

Comment: @Sabito錆兎 yep, but I don't have 2K or a diamond here ;)

Comment: Ik I flagged my post for mod intervention :) (2k can't tag with mod tags btw)

Comment: @Sabito錆兎 yeah, I know.  I don't think that's *totally* necessary, though? ;)